# Search Results TableView's position doesn't work properly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

When I start to type in the searchbar my search results tableview goes 20 px top of the searchbar. Where can I set the frame's position fixed in my code? In viewdidload or searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch,`[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.searchbar.frame.origin.y, 320, 466)];` doesn't work.

Thank you.

First 2 images, searchbar stays in the same position. But search result tableview goes up and stays there still after canceling the search. After canceling the search the searchbar goes top of the resulttableview of searchbar.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of I selected bottom line in the autosizing in xib. So I choose top line in autosizing and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this .

you need to set delta y and delta height of tableview from xib for iOS 7.

Comment: But I can't see the result tableview. How am I gonna do that?

Comment: is your table view not set empty before search?

Comment: yes it is.But I can't see it through xib. But can control from delegate methods.

Comment: ok then you need to set delta y and delta height for your search bar.

Comment: How can I set them? With which values? I didnt get the delta thing exactly.

Comment: first select ur searchbar in xib, and then see in size inspector, now you can see delta y and delta height. Have u worked before with iOS 7 ?

Comment: I'm working with 7. isn't it just about the differences of view between 6 and 7?

Comment: can u please upload screenshot ?

Comment: I add the schreenshots.